# Canvas LMS LTI 1.3 sections from an external tool

Tags: sections, lti, canvas-lms, lms

I’m looking for a way to update my Canvas LMS integrated external tool (LTI 1.3) with the currently active course sections.
Currently, I'm receiving each user's active sections (name and id) as a custom field defined in the developer key:

```
$Canvas.course.sectionIds
$com.instructure.User.sectionNames
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't provide any data about deleted sections.

What would be the best practice for getting the full list of sections in a course, particularly to discover if a section was deleted, from my external tool’s backend?